# Подсчет суммы в столбцах двух таблиц

Tags: group-by, join, объединение, mysql

Коллеги, не получается получить сумму двух столбцов из разных таблиц при помощи группировки. Выдает ерунду.

Есть две таблицы:
orders

```
+-----------+-----+
|weekModified|i_price |
+-----------+-----+
|     44             | 500
+-----------+-----+
|     44             | 150
+-----------+-----+
|     44             | 300
+-----------+-----+
|     45             | 800
+-----------+-----+
|     46             | 500
+-----------+-----+
```

expense

```
+---------+-----+
|weekCreate|i_budget |
+---------+-----+
|     43          | 1000
+---------+-----+
|     43          | 1500
+---------+-----+
|     44          | 100
+---------+-----+
|     44          | 200
+---------+-----+
|     45          | 50
+---------+-----+
```

Есть запрос

```
SELECT SUM(`i_price`), SUM(`i_budget`), `weekModified`
                    FROM `orders`
                    LEFT JOIN `expense` ON (`weekModified` = `expense`.`weekCreate`)
                    GROUP BY `weekModified`
                    ORDER BY `i_price` DESC
```

Спасибо за внимание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего в голову другого не пришло. Сам новичок :(

```
SELECT 
    SUM(i_price),budget, o.weekModified
FROM
    orders AS o
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        SUM(i_budget) as budget, weekCreate
    FROM
        expense 
    GROUP BY weekCreate) as e
    on o.weekModified=e.weekCreate
GROUP BY o.weekModified
```

Comment: INNER JOIN заменил на LEFT JOIN,
так как необходимы данные из двух таблиц, независимо от их наличия, т.к. в дальнейшем нужно будет подсчитывать чистую прибль, а это ЧП = Д - Р.
Спасибо!

Comment: @mdBender пожалуйста! Надеюсь, кто-нибудь объяснит, почему первый вариант процедуры не работает?

Comment: @argamidon тоже хочется понять, в чем причина.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем изначальном запросе, на этапе соединения таблиц, каждая из строк таблицы orders соединяется с каждой найденой строкой из таблицы expense, если условие соединения верно. Получается, что на запись с номером 44 до групировки имеем 6 строк. Предлагаю сначала сагрегировать данные, а затем их соединять. Немного не понял, в какой из таблиц может отсутствовать номер недели, поэтому нужный джоин подставите, например:

```
SELECT g_orders.WeekModified, 
       g_expense.WeekCreate, 
       g_orders.i_price, 
       g_orders.i_budget 
FROM 
    (SELECT SUM(i_price) i_price, weekModified
     FROM orders
     GROUP BY weekModified) g_orders
FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT SUM(i_budget) i_budget, weekCreate
     FROM expense
     GROUP BY weekCreate) g_expense
ON (g_orders.WeekModified = g_expense.weekCreate)
```

Comment: В mysql нету оператора FULL OUTER JOIN.